# Is it possible to attach an uploaded file to http request?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, file-upload, http-post

I have a form that submits a file to an endpoint. In theory that endpoint takes the file and attaches it to another post request that goes to the API.

I was trying to figure out how to do it with Laravel and read a few things that suggest it's not possible? That the only solution would be save it in a public place and submit the link to the API. Anyone able to shed some light on this? Below is the code that I thought would work but does not send the file.

```
$this->client->post('/api/endpoint', ['form_params' => ['file' => $request->file('file')->getRealPath()]])
```

Client being the Guzzle client.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is. [Guzzle Docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#multipart)

```
$client->request('POST', '/post', [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'foo',
            'contents' => 'data',
            'headers'  => ['X-Baz' => 'bar']
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'baz',
            'contents' => fopen('/path/to/file', 'r')
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'qux',
            'contents' => fopen('/path/to/file', 'r'),
            'filename' => 'custom_filename.txt'
        ],
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Duh. I was mentally stuck on google php stuff in general and didn't think to look through guzzle docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems fairly uncommon for APIs to handle file uploads as this is generally something a person does. If i were to do something like this I would first read the contents of the file and base64 encode it. Then send the normal Http POST request with the base64 encoded file content as a string. On the API, you could then decode it and do whatever you need to o with the file.

Dealing with base64 in PHP is fairly simple http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php